# Salvar diferença entre arrays em um novo array

Tags: python

O Script abaixo retorna a intersecção entre os arrays dentro de um novo array, eu queria salvar a diferença, no caso o que não pertence, como modificar esse script ?

**SCRIPT:**

```
values = []

a = [('SRV', 'CLIENT'),('SRV1', 'CLIENT'),('SRV2', 'CLIENT')]
b = [('SRV', 'CLIENT'),('SRV1', 'CLIENT'),('SRV3', 'CLIENT')]

gap = []
for row in a:
    if row[0] not in b:
        gap.append(row)
```

**OUTPUT:**

> [('SRV', 'CLIENT'), ('SRV1', 'CLIENT')]

[VISUALIZAR CÓDIGO](https://ideone.com/9fKWLN)

**OBJETIVO**

> [('SRV2', 'CLIENT')]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usando uma lógica parecida com a sua temos:

```
def diff(a, b):
        b = set(b)
        return [row for row in a if row not in b]

print(diff(a,b))
```

Mas acho mais simples:

```
gap = list(set(a)-set(b))
print(gap)
```

Comment: A lógica seria a mesma se os arrays fossem assim ? [u('SRV', 'CLIENT'),u('SRV1', 'CLIENT'),u('SRV2', 'CLIENT')] o exemplo representa um array preenchido com um select de um DB.

Comment: Estranho array dessa forma, ai não é array, explica melhor

Comment: Quando percorro um for dentro do array a saída é assim (u'campo',u'campo1',u'campo2')

Comment: O banco é db2,e uso as libs ibm_db e ibm_db_dbi